# Snowflake stored procedure parallel execution

Tags: stored-procedures, parallel-processing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I want to execute a single instance of Snowflake stored procedure by using Snowflake code only. Trying not to use tasks as it has external dependencies.

Just by code. Throwing all stored procedure instances in parallel.

For example `SP_INSERT_WORDS(VARCHAR)` is a stored procedure and I want to call multiple instances of the same stored procedure.

```
 SP_INSERT_WORDS('A');
 SP_INSERT_WORDS('B');
 SP_INSERT_WORDS('C');
 . . . 
 SP_INSERT_WORDS('Z');
```

Comment: When you say there are external dependencies, does that mean there is some sort of application or workflow tool that would be executing these steps?  The reason that I ask is that some of the connectors to Snowflake have the option to execute commands asynchronously.

Comment: Is this about inserting data in parallel to the same table, by running multiple insert SQL statements at the same time? This might now work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below options

1. [Use the RESULTS option in SnowSQL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-config#results).

`!set results=False;` or `snowsql -o results=False`

This option avoids the wait on the previous calls and asynchronously execute queries

2. Task execution may be viable, however it is unidirectional
3. Parallel calls from the application

[Link on restrictions for Stored Procedures](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#restrictions-on-stored-procedures).

Comment: This might be the best option. Just need to generate a file with all of the queries, and then execute that file with SnowSQL (using `snowsql -o results=False -f queries.sql`)

Answer (score 0):

Tasks do not have any external dependencies: they only require to run some SQL queries against Snowflake (not that different from procedures).

You could use a [DAG of tasks](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro#dag-of-tasks), and then you can trigger the execution of the entire DAG via `EXECUTE TASK root_task` (or you could schedule it).

Or you could run `EXECUTE TASK` for each task that you want to run in parallel, since `EXECUTE TASK` runs the tasks asynchronously. But using a root task to start them all at the same time seems easier.